# Propagating calculation along rows

Tags: r, dplyr, na

Using the following data, how is it possible to propagate the
calculation in order to fill the two `NA's`.

```r
df <- structure(
  list(
    x = c(0L, 30L, 40L),
    ed0 = c(0.24329772574554,
            NA, NA),
    kd = c(
      -0.0352736803781794,
      -0.0431451671867429,
      -0.0405766219035099
    )
  ),
  .Names = c("x", "ed0", "kd"),
  row.names = c(NA, -3L),
  class = c("tbl_df",
            "tbl", "data.frame")
)

df
#>    x       ed0          kd
#> 1  0 0.2432977 -0.03527368
#> 2 30        NA -0.04314517
#> 3 40        NA -0.04057662
```

So the value of the first `NA` would 30 + df$ed0[1] + df$kd[1] and the value of the second NA `NA` would 40 + df$ed0[2] (calculated at the previous step) + df$kd[2]. Thank you.

Comment: I just changed the code to adjust the x term as I believe that it should not be lagged as it was previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fairly straightforward method in base R.

```
with(df, cumsum(x + ifelse(is.na(ed0), 0, ed0) + c(0, head(kd, -1))))
[1]  0.2432977 30.2080240 70.1648789
```

To break this down, x remains as it is and `c(0, head(kd, -1))` setups a lagged vector of kd where the initial value is 0. `ifelse(is.na(ed0), 0, ed0)` checks if each element of ed0 is NA and replaces it with 0 if TRUE. These three terms are summed together and the resulting vector is given to `cumsum` to produce a cumulative sum. Finally, `with` is used to reduce typing.